# Relative bound of $A^r$ with respect to $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Consider a nonnegative unbounded self-adjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$; by the spectral theorem, the operator $A^r$ is well-defined for all $r\geq0$. Let us focus on the cases $r\in[1/2,1]$. By construction, the domain of $A^r$ is larger than the domain of $A$; consequently, $A^r$ is relatively bounded with respect to $A$, that is, there exist $a_r,b_r\geq0$ such that, for all $\psi\in\mathcal{D}(A)$,
\begin{equation}
\|A^r\psi\|\leq a_r\|A\psi\|+b_r\|\psi\|,
\end{equation}
with the infimum of all $a_r$ as above being the $A$-bound of $A^r$.

I am interested in estimating the $A$-bound of $A^r$. I know what happens in the two cases $r=1$ and $r=1/2$: clearly, in the first case the $A$-bound is $1$, while in the second case it can be easily proven, in full generality, that the $A$-bound of $A^{1/2}$ is zero; in other words, $A^{1/2}$ is infinitesimally bounded with respect to $A$. This can be proven by using the inequality ($\psi\in\mathcal{D}(A)$)
\begin{equation}
\|A^{1/2}\psi\|^2=\left\langle\psi,A\psi\right\rangle\leq\|\psi\|\|A\psi\|
\end{equation}
and noticing that, for all $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{equation}
0\leq\epsilon\left(\|A\psi\|^{1/2}-\frac{\|\psi\|^{1/2}}{2\epsilon}\right)^2=\epsilon\|A\psi\|-\|A\psi\|^{1/2}\|\psi\|^{1/2}+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\|\psi\|.
\end{equation}

This leads me to the following (naive) guess: the $A$-bound $a_r$ of $A^r$ for $r\in[1/2,1]$ must be some function of $r$ interpolating (monotonically?) between the values $a_{1/2}=0$ and $a_1=1$.

In order to check whether that is true, I was thinking to apply the following property: the $A$-bound of $A^r$ must be equal to
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left\|A^r(A\pm i\lambda)^{-1}\right\|,
\end{equation}
where, in the latter equation, $\|\cdot\|$ is to be interpreted as the operator norm. However, right now I have not managed to evaluate $a_r$ by means of the equation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $A$-bound $a_r$ is zero for all $r<1$: Let $\mu$ be the spectral measure of $\psi$. By the spectral theorem,
$$
\lVert A^r\psi\rVert^2=\int\lambda^{2r}\,d\mu.
$$
By Hölder's inequality with $p=1/r$ and $q=1/(1-r)$ we have
$$
\lVert A^r\psi\rVert^2\leq \left(\int\lambda^2\,d\mu\right)^r\left(\int\,d\mu\right)^{1-r}=\lVert A\psi\rVert^{2r}\lVert \psi\rVert^{2(1-r)}.
$$
Thus $\lVert A^r\psi\rVert\leq \lVert A\psi\rVert^r\lVert\psi\rVert^{1-r}$. By Young's inequality with $p$ and $q$ as above,
$$
\lVert A\psi\rVert^r\lVert\psi\rVert^{1-r}\leq \epsilon r \lVert A\psi\rVert+(1-r)\epsilon^{-r/(1-r)}\lVert\psi\rVert
$$
for all $\epsilon>0$.